# The implementation 'com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:versions has problems on layout

Tags: java, android, dependencies, material-components-android, calendarview

I want to use material-calendarview library on github(https://github.com/prolificinteractive/material-calendarview)

but I think I have some problems about implementation/version. Documentation says that 2.0.1 or 2.0.0 is the latest version of this library. When I do this:

```
implementation("com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0")
```

or

```
implementation("com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.1")
```

Here are the all versions: (2.0.1, 2.0.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.0, 1.5.0, v1.4.3, v1.4.2)
I got the problem on version 2.0.1 and 2.0.0. I do not get the problem in the rest but I want to use the latest versions.

Here is my problem
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlduG.png)
I cannot see the whole preview content in the layout, xml file. That makes my app so slow.

Here is my xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAFAFA"
    tools:context=".SecondFragment">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="25sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.124" />

    <com.prolificinteractive.materialcalendarview.MaterialCalendarView
        android:id="@+id/calendarView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:mcv_selectionColor="#000000"
        app:mcv_showOtherDates="all"
        />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I've added:

```
implementation("com.github.prolificinteractive:material-calendarview:2.0.0")
```

and:

```
maven(url = "https://jitpack.io")
```

How can I solve this problem?

I've tried all versions to solve but couldn't succeed it